# Проверка пароля на сложность

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Я хочу сделать программу для проверки сложности пароля, который вводит пользователь, но не знаю, как прописать логику проверки сложности пароля (проверка на содержание букв разного регистра, цифр, различных спец. символов и т.д.), и после проверки вывести результат: надёжный пароль или нет.

Вот небольшой кусок кода:

```
Label_1 = Label(window, text="Введите пароль для проверки")
Label_1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

txt_password = Entry(window, width=10)
txt_password.grid(column= 1, row = 0)

def clicked():
    # Проверить на сложность пароля
    pass

Btn = Button(window, text="Проверить", command=clicked)  


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Я бы просто смотрел на общее количество возможных вариантов паролей - т.е. размер множества возможных паролей...

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/password-strength/ - возможно эта библиотека вам покажется полезной.

Comment: Самый "короткий" вариант проверки пароля - тест пароля с помощью сложной регулярки, проверяющей сразу по трем-четырем групам символов. Например вот http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength (там на питоне тоже есть пример)

Answer (score 6):

```
import re

def pcheck(a: str) -> str:
    res = [re.search(r"[a-z]", a), re.search(r"[A-Z]", a), re.search(r"[0-9]", a), re.search(r"\W", a)]
    if all(res):
        return "Password is okay"
    return ("Password is weak. Add "+
            "lowercase letters, "*(res[0] is None) +
            "uppercase letters, "*(res[1] is None) +
            "digits, "*(res[2] is None) +
            "special symbols, "*(res[3] is None)+
             "then try again")
```

проверяем:

```
print(pcheck("12a3W@mя"))
print(pcheck("123W"))
print(pcheck("123w"))
print(pcheck("aWmя"))
print(pcheck("@#"))
```

Что выдаст соответственно:

```
Password is okay
Password is weak. Add lowercase letters, special symbols, then try again
Password is weak. Add uppercase letters, special symbols, then try again
Password is weak. Add digits, special symbols, then try again
Password is weak. Add lowercase letters, uppercase letters, digits, then try again
```

Comment: за `"lovercase letters, "*(res[0] is None)` :)

Comment: мне кажется идеальная функция для проверки пароля на сложность должна уметь работать с набором правил - словарь наподобие: `{"min_lowercase": 3, "min_uppercase": 2, "min_special": 1, "min_digits": 2, "min_length": 12}`. Тогда ее можно использовать в разных проектах, легко менять правила и при желании сохранять историю правил.

Answer (score 1):

Питон не знаю, потому пишу общую идею логики работы:

1. Написать проверку наличия в строке заглавных букв.
2. Написать проверку наличия в строке строчных букв
3. Написать проверку наличия в строке цифр
4. Написать проверку наличия в строке символов из заданного набора спецсимолов.
5. Если все проверки вернули true пароль достаточно сложный. Если нет - ну, тут Вам виднее, что делать.

Думаю, функции, пригодные для всех этих проверок, есть в стандартных библиотеках.

Comment: это, собственно, одно регулярное выражение. От языка мало зависящее

Comment: @splash58, сделать это можно по разному. Что касается регулярок... В силу особенностей сферы деятельности я с ними практически не знаком, потому обычно мне и не приходит в голову их предложить :))

Answer (score 1):

В данной задаче нужно будет использовать регулярные выражения. И используя ответ Юрия, можно написать алгоритм

```
import re

...

def get_strength_point(match):
    return 1 if match else 0

def clicked():
    password = txt_password.get()
    strength_point = 0
    # очко за длину
    strength_point += get_strength_point(len(password) > 8)

    # очко за наличие цифр
    strength_point += get_strength_point(re.search(r"\d", password))

    # очко за наличие букв верхнего регистра
    strength_point += get_strength_point(re.search(r"[A-Z]", password))

    # очко за наличие букв нижнего регистра
    strength_point += get_strength_point(re.search(r"[a-z]", password))

    # очко за наличие спец символов
    strength_point += get_strength_point(re.search(r"\W", password))

    if 0 <= strength_point < 2:
        return 'Легкий пароль'
    elif 2 <= strength_point < 4:
        return 'Средний пароль'
    else:
        return 'Сложный пароль'

...
```

Comment: `get_strength_point` можно заменить на `bool`: `strength_point += bool(re.search(r"\d", password))`. При проверке длины вообще можно вызов функции убрать: `strength_point += len(password) > 8`

Comment: Да верно, но отдельная функция выглядит немного информативнее)

Comment: Не особо. Хотя дело вкуса.

Comment: Да, скорее так) Ну и впринципе это ниче не поменяет)

Answer (score 1):

Есть отличный модуль для проверки сложности пароля:

[password_strength](https://pypi.org/project/password-strength/)

Вот ссылка на аналогичный вопрос с enSO:
[Checking the strength of a password (how to check conditions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709638/checking-the-strength-of-a-password-how-to-check-conditions)

`pip3 install password_strength`

```
from password_strength import PasswordStats
...
Label_1 = Label(window, text="Введите пароль для проверки")
Label_1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

txt_password = Entry(window, width=10)
txt_password.grid(column= 1, row = 0)

def clicked():
    stats = PasswordStats(txt_password.get())
    if stats.strength()>0.5:
        Label_1.configure(text="good password")
    else:
        Label_1.configure(text="bad password")

Btn = Button(window, text="Проверить", command=clicked)  


window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

ребята, если говорить о действительной проверке пароля на сложность, то главным здесь является длина пароля. И человек в состоянии ввести в качестве пароля например:

"О сколько нам открытий чудных
готовит просвещенья дух!
И опыт, сын ошибок трудных,
И гений, парадоксов друг."

Поверьте, слмать такой пароль куда сложнее чем ваши 8-ми символьные "12a3W@mя".
так что не с того начинаете, господа, если о длине пароля ни слова. :-)
Ну или пароль из 5 символов считать "сложным"

Comment: Не смотря на то, что согласен с сутью этого ответа, но все же думаю ,его вряд ли можно считать ответом на вопрос, заданные TC. Хотя минусовать все же не буду :)

Comment: Когда люди начнут массово использовать произведения Пушкина в качестве паролей, хакеры возьмут эти самые произведения Пушкина и начнут успешно подбирать пароли перебором :) Кстати, такой пароль очень долго набирать на телефоне

Comment: @andreymal - ну есть еще и Омар хаям в оригинале или греческий... ))

Comment: Анну Каренину сразу, что уж мелочиться

Comment: @Victor  вы никогда не заходили на фирму, где раз в месяц меняют пароль "авппавыаппп"!№1"  на ""вапекркп32!"  и все эти пароли приклеены на липучке к монитору?
вот ведь где все в порядке с паролями. 
А так - раз в месяц новое четверостишье каждый по выбору выучит )))

Comment: Да нет это вводить замучаешься , лучше просто хайку))